# detect if the iPhone / iPad email client was configured / valid

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, email

I had an issue with an application crashing badly while opening `MFMailComposeViewController`, it was working perfectly on the simulator and crashed on the device.

After spending some hours I realized that the reason was that the internal email client on the iPad I am using for testing was not set / configured - after setting an email on the device, all worked fine.

Thus my question: can I detect if the device email client was configured and valid to avoid the same crash again on devices which did not yet set their internal iPad / iPhone email client?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just check the canSendMail class method:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
  // Yes we can send mail.
}
```

What I do is check the method and only display the mail option if it return true.

Comment: Thank you, just want I was looking for.